# Proof regarding Squarefree numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove or find the number of squarefree number is less than $201$.

Squarefree: If a number is not divisible by the square of any positive integer, it is squarefree.  For example, $21 = 3 \cdot 7$ is a squarefree number and $20 = 2^2 \cdot 5$ is not.

Comment: What is there to prove? Do you want to find the number of square-free numbers smaller than 201?

Comment: Definition of square-free not quite right, we want not divisible by the square of any integer $\gt 1$.  Anything is divisible by $1^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computer programmer's answer: set a counter to zero; for each $a$ from 1 to 201 do the following: for each $m$ with $m\ge2$ and $m^2\le a$, see whether $a$ is divisible by $m^2$. If $a$ isn't divisible by any of those numbers $m^2$, add 1 to the counter. When you've gone through all the values of $a$, the counter holds the answer.

It's not pretty, there's plenty of room for optimization, and it won't teach you any Number Theory, but it will get you the answer.

Comment: +1  In the spirit of Project Euler, works great for 201, not so well for 10^15, maybe nothing works for 10^100 (to accuracy $\pm$1).

Answer (score 1):

Hints:  1)you can consider only the squares of primes (why?) 2) what primes do you have to worry about? 3)how many numbers below $201$ are divisible by the square of each of those primes? 4)what more do you have to worry about?